# PHP check if timestamp is greater than 24 hours from now

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I have software that needs to determine if the cutoff datetime is greater than 24 hours from now. Here is the code I have to test that.

```
 $date = strtotime("2013-07-13") + strtotime("05:30:00");

 if($date > time() + 86400) {
    echo 'yes';
 } else {
    echo 'no';
 }
```

My current date and time is 2013-07-13 2am. As you can see its only 3 hours away.
At my math thats 10800 seconds away. The function I have is returning `yes`. To me this is saying the `$date` is greater than now plus 86400 seconds when in fact its only 10800 seconds away. Should this not be returning `no`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$date = strtotime("2013-07-13") + strtotime("05:30:00");
```

should be

```
$date = strtotime("2013-07-13 05:30:00");
```

[See difference in this CodePad](http://codepad.org/lEVLGIQx)

Comment: I can see that, the problem is that the date and the time are how the values are stored in the db. They are stored as a date and a time, I cannot change it.

Comment: @Naterade Don't change them, concatenate them.

Comment: because actually `strtotime("05:30:00");` equals to `strtotime("today 05:30:00");`.

Answer (score 8):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$date = "2014-10-06";
$time = "17:37:00";

$timestamp = strtotime($date . ' ' . $time); //1373673600

// getting current date 
$cDate = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

// Getting the value of old date + 24 hours
$oldDate = $timestamp + 86400; // 86400 seconds in 24 hrs

if($oldDate > $cDate)
{
  echo 'yes';
}
else
{
  echo 'no'; //outputs no
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Store the values of date and time in separate variables and convert it into a Unix timestamp using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) after concatenating the variables.

**Code:**

```
<?php

$date = "2013-07-13";
$time = "05:30:00";

$timestamp = strtotime($date." ".$time); //1373673600

if($timestamp > time() + 86400) {
  echo 'yes';
} else {
  echo 'no'; //outputs no
}

?>
```