# Checking if post is within 24 hours

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am working in a wordpress site.. My posts have an additional date field, and I am trying to display that post only if that date field is within the next 24 hours.. I have a wordpress query that is only grabbing the most recent post, and I only want to display this div if that post date is within the next 24 hours.. Here is what I got:

```
<?php $webnars = get_posts('post_type=webinar&posts_per_page=1'); 
        foreach ( $webnars as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
            $webDate = strtotime(get_field("next_live"));
            ?>
            <div class="footer_alert">
                <div class="wrapper_inner">
                    <div class="footer_alert_inside">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Upcoming Live Webinar - <?php echo date('M j, Y',strtotime(get_field('next_live'))); ?></a><br />
                        <?php 
                        if($webDate > time() + 75000) {
                            echo 'yes';
                         } else {
                            echo 'no';
                         }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer_exit"><p><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> Exit</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php  endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

the result of running strtotime() on the date field in the post returns this at the moment: `1398124800`
Todays time() returns this at the moment: `1398095699`

post time - current time gives us this: `29101`

Now, obviously the number being returned is less than 75,000, so why is it falling into the } else { statement and echoing no? Is their something I am doing wrong with the formatting? I took most of the code from this post: [PHP check if timestamp is greater than 24 hours from now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627058/php-check-if-timestamp-is-greater-than-24-hours-from-now)

Comment: Have you checked what time zone PHP is using? If it is on a different timezone, it will be adding/minusing multiples of 24 hours

Comment: Be careful about adding/subtracting seconds, it may lead to errors when the country changes the hour (due to summer or winter). Better use strtotime(-1 day)

Comment: Or ... Try echoing `$webDate`, make sure it's formatted properly

Comment: Here's the returned value when echoing $webDate: `1398124800` and here is the time(): `1398097316`, which they're both formatted properly I believe.. @user3139907

Comment: Yeah he's answered it below Lol ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part:

```
if($webDate > time() + 75000)
```

translates with your numbers into:

```
if( 1398124800 > 1398095699 + 75000 )
```

or

```
if( 1398124800 > 1398170699 )
```

or

```
if( FALSE )
```

so your else part is activated here as expected.

Ps: Why do you use `75000`? Actually `24` hours is `86400` seconds.

Comment: From the post I linked to, I thought having the "75,000" was saying "if $webDate is greater than 75,000 seconds of the current time, do this." It seemed to work in the post I linked to.. Do you have any recommendation as to how to have PHP only return true if $webDate is 75,000 seconds greater than the current time? Also, the reason why I use 75,000 instead of 86400 is because my posts are a little over 1 day, and I was just accounting for that.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.. I added one more variable which was equal to `time() + 86400`, and then I added to the if statement `if$webDate > time() && $timeFuture > $webDate` and it worked perfectly.. Thanks for your help!